# Which business laptop product range would you recommend for the female clientele?

Tags: laptop

I'm sorry having to ask such a question and hope not hurting anyone, but I'm looking for an alternative to Dell Latitude (E6530, E6520, E6510, E6500) or Dell Precision series.

I'm a big fan of those series, and most of my customers (men or women) really like them as well.

But one a reproach that I hear from time to time, and more specifically from women, is that the laptop of those series heavy and thick. Usually, I explain that sturdiness involves some weight, but I need an alternative however.

I can't afford to sell junk even if the notebook looks pretty.

The sturdiness and the easiness of the maintenance (i.e. things like opening the computer chassis, extracting the mainboard) are important, especially as most of my customers buy a notebook for business use, and if something goes wrong they come back to me for some maintenance.

I'm aware that sturdiness and thinness/low weight are in some way antinomic but I'm looking for suggestions of laptop series that would be relatively thin/leightweight but well designed, with sturdy hinges (and good fixing of the hinges) and an enclosure that is easy to open.

I'm also looking preferably for series with a large screen (e.g. ~ 16'') altough, again, I'm aware of the paradox of a large screen and lightness.

Would you have some actual or past serie to recommend?

Comment: The notion of a single laptop range that appeals to all women seems, to put it kindly, to be as impossible as the idea of a single laptop that appeals to all men. Besides, your title does not seem to be asking the same thing as your body. In the body you say that you have some female customers who are specifically asking you for lighter laptops, but the title clearly indicates that you think you can find a single type of laptop for all your female customers.

Comment: I would ask your clients what weight they expect to see if it is even practical to get the weight down that far.  When it comes to weight tablets are the clear winner, but you sacrifice performance and features.  Macbook Air are super thin and light, but there flimsy and won't take beating.  Do they want a $1000-2000 unit they can easily break to achieve there thin and lightness goals.?